When is the Verdier localization functor an equivalence?
Let $\mathcal S$ be a thick subcategory of a triangulated category $\mathcal T$ such that the Verdier localization functor $\mathcal T\to \mathcal T/\mathcal S$ is an equivalence. Then, is it true that $\mathcal S=0$?
My reason for beleiving this is that every object in $\mathcal S$ should go to $0$ in $\mathcal T/\mathcal S$, but I can't quite make a precise proof for my claim ... please help.

By the very definition of the quotient $p : \mathcal{T} \to \mathcal{T} / \mathcal{S}$ we have $p(A)=0$ for every $A \in \mathcal{S}$ (see for example Neeman's book, Theorem 2.1.8 which constructions the Verdier quotient), which means $p(A)=p(0)$. So if $p$ is fully faithful, this would require $A=0$.
